Laravel Pest Framework / Mockery - How to run in separate process?
I have a Livewire component where i instantiate a new class called new Connector(). I want to mock this Connector with Mockery. As i understand, if you want to mock hard dependencies you can use 'overload:' while creating the mocked instance like so:
$connectorMock = Mockery::mock('overload:'.Connector::class);
But, whenever i run pest, i get the error:
Could not load mock Path\To\Connector\Connector, class already exists
I did some research and i understand why this happens, but i can't find a good solution other than using the --parallel option in my pest command (which i dislike).
In PHPUnit you can use the annotations like:
/**
 * @runInSeparateProcess
 * @preserveGlobalState disabled
 */

In Pest, i saw that you can use the annotation like so:
test('testcase description', function () {

})->setRunInSeparateProcess(true);

But this does not work either except when i use --parallel option.
Does anyone know how i can run a Pest test in a separate process without using --parallel? Thanks in advance.
Note: i'm also aware that i could use dependency injection in the Livewire's mount() function. Unfortunately i cannot do that as the piece of code is called while the component is initialising because i'm dealing with huge page load because of lots of data.
Example application:
example.blade.php -> livewire blade view
<div wire:init="getData">
 Some blade stuff here
</div>

example.php -> livewire component
public function getData(Collection $collection)
{
  $connector = new Connector(); // This i need to mock

  // More code
}


if it is using the new keyword, it is extremely complex to get over it, I would say impossible... can't you change that code to resolve(Connector::class);?
